# Delphi TDatabase parameters for Firebird confusion

Tags: delphi, firebird, bde

I've created a Data Source through the control panel successfully and used it with TTable and TQuery and TDBGrid, now I want to learn how to use TDatabase to connect to my Firebird DB, I have selected the Firebird Interbase Driver and selected "defaults". Do I have to complete all the parameters that pop up? Can I delete those I don't want to interfere with (don't understand)?
In fact the only ones I have tried to set are

```
DATABASE NAME=localhost:c:\fbdb\abook.fdb
USERNAME=SYSDBA
PASSWORD=masterkey
```

Can someone help me with the rest, I keep getting

> invalid configuration parameter

*The company I am joining has existing apps using the BDE and require me to train myself in Delphi 7, Firebird, BDE, Report Builder before I join.*

Comment: Are you aware that BDE is deprecated since Delphi 6 —more than 10 years ago—? If you're just learning, my advise is to try dbExpress (TSQLConnection, TSQLQuery, etc.)

Comment: @Denver Naidoo, which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: I recall the exact OP being advised in a prior question about the same thing. BDE should be considered no more, it's like riding a bicycle at a nascar race.

Comment: Question: Do you plan on distributing this application to anyone? If so, be aware of the complications installing BDE to Windows Vista and up. Major incompatibility.

Comment: you could change your USERNAME parameter to USER_NAME instead. But as @jachguate suggested, don't use BDE, use DBExpress or any number of free FB components to connect.

Comment: @Jerry I never seen an incompatibility error installing the BDE in vista or even windows 7.

Comment: Try turning your UAC settings all the way up and try to modify the BDE settings in the control panel. You will face hell. Also, try using BDE to transfer a very large `BLOB` and see that it's not that simple. Also, ADO has extremely better performance for us than BDE ever offered. We only kept BDE capabilities for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Jerry, I see why it doesn't represent a problem for me, the applications still uses the BDE doesn't require any modification via control panel, just the library to be present, because the app auto-configures what is needed in each session/connection at runtime. The work with BLOBs appear to function properly, but I'm not aware of any very large BLOB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a BDE alias (in BDE Administrator under Control Panel or from some Delphi menu).

In your application double-click on the `TDatabase`. Here you give a `Name`, you pick your newly created `Alias name` from the list and you add these `Parameter overrides`:

```
USER NAME=SYSDBA
PASSWORD=masterkey
SQLDIALECT=3
```

Click OK and try to set `Connected` property to True, under `TDatabase` properties.